# tornado testing @tornado.web.authenticated

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to test tornado using [AsyncHTTPTestCase](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/testing.html?highlight=asynchttptestcase#tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase). I want to test handlers  marked with the @tornado.web.authenticated annotation. Because this handler requires authentication we must login first or somehow fool it in thinking we are authenticated in our test code

```
class HandlerToTest(BaseHandler):
  @tornado.web.authenticated
  def get(self):
    self.render("hello.html", user=self.get_current_user() )
```

According to [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/python-tornado/6HW30emjops) we can fudge the cookies. I have got this working but according to Ben Darnell tornado maintainer this is not recommended. Ben recommends using the [CookieLib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar) module but that requires the 'info' part of the response which we don't have.

Another [blog post suggests mocking](http://www.a13x.info/2011/08/testing-authenticated-handlers-in.html) the get_current_user() call using [mox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/). However I can not get the sample code in the blog working.

So my question is:
What is the best way of testing the handlers marked as authenticated? And can someone point me to a sample application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually got Mocks working. Don't know if this is the 'best way' but it might be useful to someone in the future. This code tests 2 handlers and mocks the `get_current_user()` call generated by `@tornado.web.authenticated`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import os, os.path, sys
import tornado.web
import tornado.testing
import mox

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_login_url(self):
        return u"/login"

    def get_current_user(self):
        user_json = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
        if user_json:
            return tornado.escape.json_decode(user_json)
        else:
            return None

class HelloHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render("protected.html")


class Protected(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        # get an user from somewhere
        return "andy"

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render("protected.html")


class TestAuthenticatedHandlers(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        self.mox = mox.Mox()
        app = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/protected', Protected),
            (r'/hello', HelloHandler)
        ])
        return app

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mox.UnsetStubs()
        self.mox.ResetAll()

    def test_new_admin(self):
        self.mox.StubOutWithMock(Protected, 'get_current_user', use_mock_anything=True)
        Protected.get_current_user().AndReturn("test_user")
        self.mox.ReplayAll()
        resp = self.fetch('/protected')
        self.assertEqual(resp.code, 200)
        self.mox.VerifyAll()

    def test_hello_page(self):
        self.mox.StubOutWithMock(HelloHandler, 'get_current_user', use_mock_anything=True)
        HelloHandler.get_current_user().AndReturn("test_user")
        self.mox.ReplayAll()
        resp = self.fetch('/hello')
        self.assertEqual(resp.code, 200)
        self.assertIn( "Hello", resp.body )
        self.mox.VerifyAll()
```

Comment: Thanks, for the very helpful example!

Answer (score 0):

This Torando utils library also allows you to test authenticated handlers: [tornado_utils/http_test_client.py](https://github.com/peterbe/tornado-utils)

Answer (score -2):

In my case simply works:

```
BaseHandler.get_current_user = lambda x: {'username': 'user', 'email': 'user@ex.com'}
```

Comment: Or add more detail to explain how it addresses the question.

Comment: I mean that BaseHandler method get_current_user is possible to override using any function, outside AsyncHTTPTestCase. In other side tornado  authenticated decorator simply checks value of self.current_user